strange Polyfit behaviour in python
I have a dataset as in seen blue plot, the orange line is the trend line generated by poly fit. it seems like fit curve needs to be flipped on Y axis and rotated 90 degree clockwise. When I rotate my dataset to place the concave opening facing upside, polyfit works just fine. What is the reason of this behaviour ?

These are the images fitted correctly when the dataset is rotated -90 and 90 degrees respectively


You can find the code to generate charts below
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.close

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 10))

if (1):
    f = rotate_data_List([dataV[0]],-90)
else:
    f = dataV

x = f[0][:,0] 
y = f[0][:,1] 
ax.plot( x , y , 'o' )

coeff = np.polyfit(x,y,2)
z = np.poly1d(coeff)
yn = z(x)

ax.plot( x,yn)

plt.show()


scipy.optimize.curve_fit only fits explicit curves. Hence the need for rotation to make your curve explicit.
